# Quick Sort Algorithm showing Wrong Output

Tags: java, sorting, data-structures, quicksort

I have written code of Quick Sort but it is showing Exception Array Index Out of bound.This works properly when written in C but in Java it is not working.Please tell what is the problem with it.Any Suggestion is appreciated.It is two way partition standard CLRS algorithm.

```
package Sorting;

public class QuickSort {

    public static void main(String arg[]) {
        int a[] = { 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 };

        Sort(a, 0, a.length - 1);
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            System.out.print(" " + a[i]);
        }

    }

    private static void Sort(int[] a, int i, int j) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (i < j) {
            int k = Partition(a, i, j);
            Sort(a, i, k - 1);
            Sort(a, k + 1, j);

        }
    }

    private static int Partition(int[] a, int i, int j) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int temp;
        int x = a[j];
        int l = i - 1;
        for (int n = i; n < j; n++) {
            if (a[n] >= x) {
                l++;
                temp = a[l];
                a[l] = a[n];
                a[n] = temp;
            }
        }
        temp = a[x];
        a[x] = a[l + 1];
        a[l + 1] = temp;
        return l + 1;

    }
}
```

Output: 9 3 5 7 4 1 6 2 8

Comment: Where does the error occur?

Comment: I dont want to spend time going into the logic here but the error is in your for loop in partition.
        for (int n = i; i < j; n++) 
int i never gets incremented in the loop so this will run forever

Comment: At face value, `Partition` can't work. See the `for` loop.  The condition is `i < j`.  Neither `i` nor `j` changes in the body.  Once execution enters, it's the Hotel California: "You can check out any time you like, but you can never leave."

Comment: @user3728933 I dont think you fully understand the quick sort algorithm. Your code doesnt look like its choosing a pivot to sort around at all/correctly. Here is a good link which explains how quick sort works https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y_G9BkAm6B8

Comment: Now your post says there is an out of bounds error and also gives output. Which is it? Assuming there is no more bounds error, I suggest you insert trace code (`System.err.print`), to figure out why `Partition` is not working. You will never learn if we debug your program for you.

Comment: @I-LOVE-2-REVIVE His partition code always chooses `a[j]` as the pivot (which is `x`).  His program is close but has silly bugs that he needs to find by himself.

Answer (score 2):

there are some minor mistakes in your code, here is the updated code:

```
    private static int Partition(int[] a, int i, int j) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
    int temp;
    int x = a[j];
    int l = i - 1;
    for (int n = i; n < j; n++) {
        if (a[n] <= x) {      /*******Condition was wrong******/
            l++;
            temp = a[l];
            a[l] = a[n];
            a[n] = temp;
        }
    }
    temp = a[j];      /******a[j] not a[x] x is value of pivot element******/
    a[j] = a[l + 1];
    a[l + 1] = temp;
    return l + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`i` is always lower than `j` bacause i anj doesn't change

```
for (int n = i; i < j; n++)
```

so you have an endless loop.

Comment: No, because `a[n]` will cause an exception as soon as n>=a.size()

Comment: @ammoQ That is right. But n > a.size() because of the endless loop.

Comment: @user3728933  The question "why is my code not working" is off-topic.

Comment: @Jenes Not Working Output is 1 3 5 4 6 7 2 8 9

Comment: [Here you have a working implementation](http://www.java-uni.de/index.php?Seite=86)

Answer (score 1):

In this loop in `partition`:

```
for (int n = i; i < j; n++)
```

You probably meant `n<j` than `i<j`. `i` never changesm so `i<j` is always true. `n` eventually becomes `9`. `a[9]` does not exist, so the exception.

Comment: Now it is showing wrong output ,exception is removed.

Comment: Exception is removed = your question is answered. Now you need to debug why it is not working :-) Please post any specific questions and we can help.

Comment: Okk but question is updated now.If you can help please do.Effort is appreciated.